# Yahoo RangeSeekBar

Tags: android, android-seekbar, rangeseekbar

In my app, I'm using the following library:

```
'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'
```

I define it like: in my .xml

```
<com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/rskFreq"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

However, I need to hide or delete the labels of Min / Max, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it. There's is no function defined in the library.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
rsb:showLabels="false"
```

Comment: This works (to bad they are hidden not gone) but with that when the left thumb goes to the min position all just dissapear.. wtf?

Comment: I want to change the colour of Rangeseekbar.How can i do this